# How to compare two large text files in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, text, nlp, text-processing

**Datasets**: I have two different text datasets(large text files for train and test that each one includes 30,000 sentences). a part of data is like the following:
"
the fulton county grand jury said friday an investigation of atlanta's recent primary election produced `` no evidence '' that any irregularities took place .
"

**Question**: How can I replace every word in the test data not seen in training with the word "unk" in Python?

**My solution**: Should I use the "nested for-loops" to compare all words of the train data with all words of the test data and also the "if-statement" to say if any word in test data is not in train data then replace with "unk" ?

```
#open text file and assign it to varaible with the name "readfile"
readfile1= open('train.txt','r')
#create the new empty text file with the new name and then assign it to variable 
# with the name "writefile". now this file is ready for writing in that
writefile=open('test.txt','w')
for word1 in readfile1:
    for word2 in readfile2:
        if (word1!=word2):
            word2='unk'
writefile.close()
```

Comment: Some sample code from your project would be excellent to include with your question.

Comment: "Should I use the "nested for-loops"" - probably not. Ignoring the possibility that there might be some library for this kind of thing, look at [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set) (particularly [set difference](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference)) and [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do not use the `ml` tag for machine learning questions (see the [tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info)); also, question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` (both tags removed & replaced with `text` and `text-processing`)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

1. convert your training set into a dict with the work as the key and count as the value. Eg:

```
    {"Hello":1,
    "World":2}
```

2. For every word in the test set try to access the word in dict if it's not there then replace with 'unk'.

```
     def fun(testset):
            newtestset= testset
            for word in testset:
             try:
              Count = word_dict['Hello']
             except:
              newtestset.replace(word,'unk')
            return newtestset
```

3. to generate the dict for all of the txt file:

```
def freq(str): 
    
    out_dict = {}
    # break the string into list of words 
    str_list = str.split() 
  
    # gives set of unique words 
    unique_words = set(str_list) 

    for word in unique_words:
        out_dict[word] = str_list.count(word)
    return out_dict
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Praveen. Would you please tell me how to make the dictionary set which includes of each word and its count? (as I said, each of my train and test datasets is a large text file. a text file that includes more than 20,000 sentences).

Comment: Modified the answer to handle this.